# Использование new

Tags: c++

В нескольких примерах на просторах сети можно найти следующие вещи.
Допустим имеем несколько определений:

```
class foo{
protected:
    int* numb;
public: 
    foo(int* ptr_to_numb){
        this->number = ptr_to_numb;
    }

    ~foo(){
        delete this->numb;
    }
}

void show_int(int* ptr_to_number){
    std::cout << *ptr_to_number << std::endl;
}
```

Затем выполним:

```
foo exmpl(new int(7));
show_int(new int(7));
```

Что будет с аргументами, переданными в конструктор и функцию? (Если не принимать во внимание оптимизаций компилятора)

Comment: А вот для этого существуют умные указатели (smart_ptr), с подсчетом числа активных ссылок.

Comment: Что значит "как быть"? Он же у вас явно очищается в деструкторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере `delete` уже наличествует в деструкторе `foo`. Именно оно, по замыслу автора класса, и должно удалить объект, указатель на который вы передавали в конструктор.

---

Что касается варианта с функцией, то в вашем варианте вы можете либо удалить объект внутри функции, либо где-то запомнить указатель на него для долгосрочного хранения (и последующего удаления).

То, что написано в варианте с функцией у вас сейчас, порождает классическую утечку памяти - объект не удаляется и доступ к нему теряется безвозвратно.

Comment: Хорошо, это понятно. А что если мы, скажем передали такой аргумент в функцию, которая не предусматривает удаление этого объекта. *Скорректирую пример

Comment: @Артём Зыктин: Вариант с фукцией в вашем примере объект не удаляет вообще, а вместо этого навсегда теряет всякий доступ к нему. Получается утечка памяти.